# Difference between @cascade(cascadeType.Delete) and cascade=cascadeType.Delete

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate.In a project that i'm using it has been used @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
@ManyToOne
annotations in entity class.But I found a another annotation
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DELETE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY). Is there any difference in these two annotations.If there are differences please explain.

Comment: Be careful that you don't mix up `JPA` and `Hibernate` annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc says it all. [`Cascade` javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html) says:

> Apply a cascade strategy on an association. Used to apply **Hibernate specific cascades**. For JPA cascading, prefer using CascadeType on OneToOne, OneToMany, etc. Hibernate will merge together both sets of cascades.

(emphasis mine)

And the javadoc of [`CascadeType.DELETE`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#DELETE) says;

> Corresponds to the Hibernate native DELETE action.

So, if you stick to the standard JPA API, or to methods of Session that are standard JPA methods (persist(), merge(), remove(), etc.), then you should never have to use the Hibernate-proprietary Cascade annotation.

But if you use Hibernate-proprietary methods like save(), saveOrUpdate(), update(), delete(), and you want cascading applied to those methods, then you'll need to use Cascade, because there is no way, using the JPA standard annotations, to specify behavior for methods that don't exist in JPA (other than cascade = ALL, which covers all the operations, even the Hibernate-specific ones)